# Updating file geo database table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, arcmap, file-geodatabase

I have an input csv file that I process using a python script and generate a new output csv file. I then, in the same python script use [Table to Table (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000027000000) in order to store the data from the output csv file in a file geo database.

The information in the input csv file will change but I'm currently only able to create a new and not update the table. So the question is, how can I update the table or if there's a smarter solution to this problem than generating and converting csv files?

Comment: You could use cursors to read the data from the csv and write it to your GDB table. But without knowing what kind of changes you have, it's hard to say.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, I will look in to cursors but probably I will clear the table in the geodatabase and repopulate it with data from the input csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [Append tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000). So if your new data is EXACTLY the same format you could append the data to an existing table. Think of it as adding more rows to the end of the table with your new data.

Comment: @artwork21 why would you need an advance license level? The help file clearly indicates it works at all license levels. What was your thinking that would require a higher license level? Just curious?

Comment: My mistake was looking at a different tool.

Comment: I was getting worried I thought you knew some killer nugget of information that stopped the Append tool working. I know the Union tool for example limits the number of layers for a basic license.

Comment: @Hornbydd I also want to update rows but found the required tools (delete) in the toolset you linked, thanks!